# Buddypress add sub menus under Group home page

Tags: submenu, buddypress

I'm using Buddypress 1.8.1

I need to add sub menus under group home page. When I click home menu there should be 2 sub menus under home menu.

I already created sub pages. But I couldn't able to add sub menus under home menu.

something like this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `bp_core_new_subnav_item()` could be the function you're looking for. You'd use it something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'name'            => 'Snazzy Subnav', // Display name for the nav item
    'slug'            => 'snazzy', // URL slug for the nav item
    'parent_slug'     => 'home', // URL slug of the parent nav item
    'parent_url'      => false, // URL of the parent item
    'item_css_id'     => 'snazzy-id', // The CSS ID to apply to the HTML of the nav item
    'user_has_access' => true,  // Can the logged in user see this nav item?
    'site_admin_only' => false, // Can only site admins see this nav item?
    'position'        => 90,    // Index of where this nav item should be positioned
    'screen_function' => false // The name of the function to run when clicked
);

bp_core_new_subnav_item( $args )
```

Comment: In your theme's functions.php but note the code is an example, you'd need to change the values.